# How can I add a QWidget as a sub widget to another QWidget after init?

Tags: qt, qwidget

What I want to do is quite easy. I want to add a QLabel to a QFrame(or a QWidget) whenever I triggered some slot.

If I put the code below in `MainWindow`'s constructor, even after `ui->setupUI(this)`:

```
QLabel * pLabel = new QLabel("abc", ui->frame);
```

this works

However, if I move this line to a slot of `MainWindow`, e.g. `shortcut`, it won't show anything.
How can I add this correct?

Note: I do not want to add it to layout. I need it overlay on others and I need to manage the exact position of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `show()` explicitly after creating the `QLabel`

```
QLabel * pLabel = new QLabel("abc", ui->frame);
pLabel->show();
```

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget):

> ...If you add a child widget to an already visible widget you must
>   explicitly show the child to make it visible...